# Telescopic surf fishing rods - Are less segments better?

Tags: fishing, sea, beach, fishing-tackle

I am looking for a telescopic surf fishing rod of about 14 feet length & lure weight up to 250grams/8oz.

Is it better if a telescopic surf rod has less segments or does it not matter ?

This one is [14ft, 4 segments & 6 guides](https://www.waveinn.com/nautical-fishing/tubertini-blaster-telesurf/1326660/p)
This one is [14 ft, 7 segments & 6 guides -](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A13ZKYQ)
This one (from an obscure USA company) is [14ft, 4 segments, 5 guides](http://www.ticaamerica.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=30&Itemid=267)

Answer (score 1):

Like most things its a tradeoff.

More segments,

- Smaller collapsible size,
- More eyelets to run the string through
- Can be more expensive.

Fewer segments,

- Fewer parts to break
- Fewer weak joints

I know for sure that more segments in a fly fishing rod make for a better one.

Comment: How do you know that more segments in a fly fishing rod is better ?

Comment: @AgileFisherman Because I have one

Comment: Yes, but what about the rod makes it better in your opinion ? For example,it can cast farther, it can support heavier loads etc..

Comment: @AgileFisherman mostly it’s easier to carry since it’s smaller

Comment: While I would not argue that more segments in a fly fishing rod are necessarily WORSE than single piece units ANYMORE, I certainly don't agree that they are intrinsically better. It could be easier to carry but if portability is not a concern, then by virtually every other metric (cost, durability, fishability) the single piece rod - or fewer pieces - offers advantages, however marginal.